# Как это работает? Java Fibonacci

Tags: java, числа, числа-фибоначчи

Объясните пожалуйста, каким образом Java из этого кода получает значение чисел Фибоначи?  Все логично кроме b=a-b??

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    System.out.print(a+" ");
    a = a+b;
    b=a-b;
}
```

Comment: А вы дебажить пробовали? И на каждом ходу смотреть что происходит.

Comment: Это такой способ в `b` сохранить старое значение `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рассмотрим это с математической точки зрения. Пусть в `n`-й итерации цикла `a = x`, `b = y`. Тогда при выполнении строчки `a = a + b` получится, что `a = x + y`. При последующем исполнении строчки `b = a - b` получим `b = (x + y) - y = x`. Таким образом, в `b` получаем предыдущее значение `a`, а в `a` - следующее значение, вычисленное по правилам формирования последовательности Фибоначчи.